# MediaCodec Buffer Underflow exce

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I have a h264 stream and want to decode using MediaCodec in `Android 4.1.2`

The stream is decodable using ffmpeg, but it's slow, so i want to use MediaCodec. The Mobile is Samsung Galaxy S3

On a button click, a new activity will be started.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    test = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
    test.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setContentView(test);
}
```

In the callback

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //codedBuffer = new byte[1536000];
    if(wt == null){
        wt = new RenderThread(arg0.getSurface());
        wt.start();
    }

}
```

where RenderThread is

```
public void run() {
formatIn = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 480, 800);
coder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
if(formatIn != null)
    coder.configure(formatIn, mSurface, null, 0);
coder.start();
ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = coder.getInputBuffers();
ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = coder.getOutputBuffers();
mBufferInfo = new BufferInfo();
while(!Thread.interrupted()){

    while(waitForStream){
        Thread.yield();
}
if(!EOS ){

int inBufIndex = coder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
if(inBufIndex != -1){
ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inBufIndex]; 
buffer.put(receivebuffer,0,size);
coder.queueInputBuffer(inBufIndex, 0, size, 0,0);
}
int outBufIndex = coder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, 10000);
switch (outBufIndex) {
case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
outputBuffers = coder.getOutputBuffers();
break;
case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " );
break;
case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
    break;
default:
//  ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outBufIndex];
//  buffer.get(decodedBuffer);
    coder.releaseOutputBuffer(outBufIndex, true);
}
}
```

The `decodedBuffer` is a byte[1536000]

### The updated error log is

```
02-03 05:53:20.065: I/OMXClient(12333): Using client-side OMX mux.
02-03 05:53:20.145: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.170: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.195: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.215: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.270: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.290: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.295: E/SpannableStringBuilder(12333): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-03 05:53:20.295: E/SpannableStringBuilder(12333): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-03 05:53:20.310: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.330: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.355: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.375: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.395: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.410: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.420: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.425: D/DecodeActivity(12333): New format 
02-03 05:53:20.485: D/DecodeActivity(12333): dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!
02-03 05:53:20.605: W/dalvikvm(12333): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40de32a0)
02-03 05:53:20.605: E/AndroidRuntime(12333): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-658
02-03 05:53:20.605: E/AndroidRuntime(12333): java.nio.BufferOverflowException
02-03 05:53:20.605: E/AndroidRuntime(12333):    at java.nio.Buffer.checkPutBounds(Buffer.java:189)
02-03 05:53:20.605: E/AndroidRuntime(12333):    at java.nio.ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.put(ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.java:100)
02-03 05:53:20.605: E/AndroidRuntime(12333):    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:712)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a `get()` call, I assume you're failing here:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outBufIndex];
buffer.get(decodedBuffer);
```

If you look at the CTS [EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest), which works with raw YUV data, you'll see an extra bit:

```
ByteBuffer outputFrame = decoderOutputBuffers[decoderStatus];
outputFrame.position(info.offset);
outputFrame.limit(info.offset + info.size);
```

The `MediaCodec` code doesn't read or update the `ByteBuffer` state, so you have to do it explicitly.  This applies to the input side too.

The buffer-to-buffer and buffer-to-surface portions of EncodeDecodeTest will work with API 16, and are useful to examine.  The surface-to-surface tests require API 18.

One thing you'll find is that the test doesn't extracting the buffer contents to a fixed-size array, because the decoded size of the frame is not knowable statically.  You need to know the color-format of the output, and that will vary from one device to another.  You'll also find that `checkFrame()` gives up entirely on some devices because it doesn't understand the frame format.

If you can decode to a Surface, your code can work like `checkSurfaceFrame()` instead, where you don't care about the buffer format because OpenGL ES does all the work.  See also [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest).

Comment: as i don't want to use `buffer.get()` call i just comment it, it's working,, but a new problem,, Now i get `BufferOverFlow` exception! I will updates the log in the question regardingly

Comment: i see the decoded frame(may be the first decoded frame) before i get `BufferOverFlow` problem

Comment: Thank you fadden.. It solved with a `clear()` call before `put()` call

Comment: Thanks a lot, fadden. Without that "extra bit", an app gets java.nio.BufferUnderflowException EXACTLY after decoding successfully 36 times. This is 100% reproducible.  It is for decoding audio.